# how to replace Hyperbole implicit action buttons with equivalent org-mode functionality?

Tags: org-mode, keyboard-macros, hyperbole

I like using the [Hyperbole implicit buttons](https://www.gnu.org/software/hyperbole/FAST-DEMO) as a very easy way to take actions by just doing `M-RET` on some text -- for example, I want to jump straight to the org-mode agenda for the day, so I put `{C-c a a}` in my buffer, and just hit `M-RET` there.

But...Hyperbole is weird. I've just never understood it. It does strange
things when initializing (to keybindings; to [opening buffers named
`BLANK`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/78601/19526)) when
initializing, and it just doesn't click for me. Since the only Hyperbole
thing I want are those `{ }` and `< >` buttons, I want to replace them
and stop using Hyperbole, since I use so little of it, and so much of org-mode's functionality.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use [`elisp:` org-mode links](https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html) more, and combining them with named keyboard macros gives us this solution:

For example, starting the org agenda for the current day: I want to do the same thing that `C-c a a` does. Hyperbole's implicit buttons let me just do `M-RET` on `{C-c a a}`. We can do the same thing in org:

1. [Record a keyboard macro](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/keyboard-macros-are-misunderstood) that does what you want. Or...don't, and just take your existing Hyperbole thing and copy the relevant string. Or use the strategy below with `funcall` and `kmacro`.
2. Name the macro: `name-last-kbd-macro`. Call that `my-start-org-agenda`.
3. Insert the macro with `insert-kbd-macro` to give it an alias that the `elisp:` link can use. That gives me:

```lisp
(defalias 'start-org-agenda
  (kmacro "C-c a a"))
```

4. Make elisp call that: in your org-mode buffer, just put in `elisp:start-org-agenda` or `[[elisp:start-org-agenda][run org agenda!]]`.

Now you follow the org mode link as usual, and it does the same thing.

You may consider [marking that as safe to call](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/69502/19526) or otherwise making `org` not pester you about evaluating that lisp.

That lets me replace almost all of my Hyperbole use. And for slightly more complex bits, you can write a function to "parametrize" your call: do, say,

```lisp
(defun start-org-agenda-and-send-useless-message (msg)
   (start-org-agenda)
   (message "You said '%s'." msg))
```

and make your link on: `[[elisp:(start-org-agenda-and-send-useless-message "from an elisp link")][hello]]`.

If you want to parameterize the actual keyboard macro, it seems you can use `funcall`: continuing my silly example with the org-mode agenda, say you want a function that will launch various flavors of the agenda via `C-c a TYPE`:

```lisp
(defun do-some-agenda-command (cmd)
  "Launch the org agenda with command `cmd'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((the-macro-string (format "C-c a %s" cmd)))
    (funcall (kmacro the-macro-string))))
```

Then replace Hyperbole things like `{C-c a a}` and `{C-c a t}` with `elisp:(do-some-agenda command "a")` and `elisp:(do-some-agenda-command "t")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new link type in Org that runs whatever function you'd like when you follow the link. Here for example I define a new `kbd` link type that lets you run keyboard macros just like Hyperbole's {} key series notation:

```
(org-link-set-parameters
 "kbd"
 :follow
 (lambda (kmacro arg)
   (kmacro-call-macro arg t nil (kbd kmacro))))
```

Now you can use links like: `<kbd:C-c a a>` (or `[[kbd:C-c a a]]` if you prefer that link notation). And just in case let me mention that Org links are *not* limited to Org buffers! You can use the command `org-open-at-point-global` to open any Org link in any buffer at all.